# Laplacian operator on $L^2(\Omega)$?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ be an open subset and $\displaystyle \Delta:=-\sum_{j=1}^n D_j^2$ be the Laplacian operator.

I have some questions concearning this operator:

$(i)$ Does it map $L^2(\Omega)$ into itself? If it fails, does it map $C^\infty_0(\Omega)$ into $L^2(\Omega)$?

$(ii)$ In the case $\Delta(L^2(\Omega))\subset L^2(\Omega)$, is it self-adjoint?

Thanks

Comment: When you apply the Laplacian operator, you have to use two derivatives. Thus, if by $\Delta$ in $L^2(\Omega)$, you mean in the distributional sense then, $\Delta: L^2(\Omega)\to H^{-2}(\Omega)$.

Comment: Sure, I had forgotten $H^{0}(\Omega)=L^2(\Omega)$ =) Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the Laplacian does not map $L^2$ to $L^2$. But one can consider it as an [unbounded operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbounded_operator) from a dense subspace of $L^2$ into $L^2$. This dense subset includes $C_0^\infty$, since the Laplacian maps  $C_0^\infty$ into $C_0^\infty$.

To discuss self-adjointness, one must impose boundary conditions and *close* the operator. I suggest reading a book about such things: e.g., *Spectral Theory and Differential Operators* by Davies, chapter 1.

Comment: Could you explain more? Especially about how can we consider it as an unbounded operator from a dense space of $L^2$.